# Bash script - copy the last line of files to another files

Tags: linux, bash

I need to copy only the last line of a lot of files to another file. How can I do that? Please help me.

I know tail to take the last file and `>` to put that to other file but I can do the same thing to a lot of files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
tail -qn 1 inputfile1 inputfile2 ... > outputfile
```

`-n 1` for outputting only the last line, `-q` for suppressing the header.

See:

```
man tail
```